# Are locks necessary for writing with fwrite from parallel processes in R?

Tags: r, multithreading, parallel-processing, data.table, hpc

I have an intensive simulation task that is ran in parallel on a high performance cluster.

Each thread (~3000) is using an R scripts to write the simulation output with the `fwrite` function of the `data.table` package.

Our IT-Guy told me to use locks. So I use the flock package to lock the file while all threads are writing to it.

But this created a new bottleneck. Most of the time the processes wait until they can write. Now I was wondering how can I evaluate whether the lock is really necessary? To me it just seems very weird that more than 90 % of the processing time for all jobs is spent on waiting for the lock.

Can anyone tell me if it really is necessary to use locks when I only append results to a csv with the `fwrite` function and the argument `append = T`?

Edit:
I already tried writing individual files and merge them in various ways after all jobs were completed. But merging took also too long to be acceptable.

It still seems to be the best way to just write all simulation results to one file without lock. This works very fast and I did not find errors when doing it without the lock for a smaller number of simulations.

Could writing without lock cause some problems that will be unnoticed after running millions of simulations?

Comment: Are these threads writing to the same file? Can't you just have each process write to a different file? Then locks should not be necessary. The files could be merged in a post-processing step.

Comment: Yes they write to one file. I already tried the option you proposed. But reading and merging ~100k files that sum up to > 100 mb apparently takes a lot of time as well. So this option does not really give an advantage in terms of processing time.

Comment: How are you reading and merging them? That step should be much faster than any approach that involves a shared file that needs to be locked. Of course, the best approach would be to use a database.

Comment: I used ">>" to append the files on the cluster and I also tried it with some R functions. What would be your suggestion for using a data base? I considered a data base but thought that it might be too much overhead again for just writing lines to a file.

Comment: Can you clarify: Each file is only one line? Why are you writing to file at all? The proper R way would be to return the result from each thread in RAM and combine it in memory. E.g., the `foreach` package makes that easy.

Comment: Each file are several lines from 1 to 10k. What you are proposing requires me to run the whole thing from one R-Script and this is not possible because of the way parallelization is done on our HPI. Parallelization with foreach does not work properly as I have to use MPI to distribute the processes. This however, is poorly documented for R on our HPI and does not work well with R. As a consequence each thread executes an independent R session where the scripts are running with different parameters. This produces output tables of several lines for each thread.

Comment: Anyway. Those are details which would not be important if I knew if the filelock can be removed.

Comment: Well, I would save to a separate file from each thread, `lapply(..., fread)` over the files and use, e.g., `rbindlist`. Or use other software to combine the files (sed, awk, ...).

Comment: I also did this. But lapply with fread and rbindlist fails because all files together are too large and it results in a “cannot allocate vector of xGB error”.

Comment: Then do it in chunks ...

Comment: This ends up taking too long if I scale it up to more simulations.

Comment: I have suggested two, maybe three viable solutions that should work better than what you have been trying. I'm not sure what else you hope for. I would set up a database.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! But to me it still seems to be the best way to just write all simulation results to one file without lock. This works very fast and I did not find errors when doing it without the lock for a smaller number of simulations. I want to know whether writing without lock could cause some problems that will be unnoticed after running millions of simulations. I will edit the question to be more precise on what I want to know.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will encounter issues of two threads write to the file simultaneously. Since `fwrite` is very fast and your files small, this is unlikely but not impossible for each write. Since you have so many writes it becomes probable that it happens sooner or later.

Comment: Ok. So I will look into the data base thing. Which package would you start with? I have no experience in working with data bases in R.

Comment: At my institute we use a PostgreSQL database and the `RPostgres` package. Faster solutions might exist. I'm not a database expert.

Answer (score 1):

*(I started writing a few comments to this effect, then decided to wrap them up in an answer. This isn't a perfect step-by-step solution, but your situation is not so simple, and quick-fixes are likely to have unintended side-effects in the long-term.)*

I completely agree that relying on file-locking is not a good path. Even if the shared filesystem<sup>[1]</sup> supports them "fully" (many claim it but with caveats and/or corner-cases), they almost always have some form of performance penalty. Since the only time you need the data all together is at data harvesting (not mid-processing), the simplest approach in my mind is to write to individual files.

When the whole processing is complete, either (a) combine all files into one (simple bash scripts) and bulk-insert into a database; (b) combine into several big files (again, bash scripts) that are small enough to be read into R; or (c) file-by-file insert into the database.

1. Combine all files into one large file. Using `bash`, this might be as simple as

   ```sh
   find mypath -name out.csv -print0 | xargs -0 cat > onebigfile.csv
   ```

   Where `mypath` is the directory under which all of your files are contained, and each process is creating its own `out.csv` file within a unique sub-directory. This is not a perfect assumption, but the premise is that if each process creates a file, you should be able to uniquely identify those output files from all other files/directories under the path. From there, the `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 cat > onebigfile.csv` is I believe the best way to combine them all.

   From here, I think you have three options:

   1. Insert into a server-based database (postgresql, sql server, mariadb, etc) using the best bulk-insert tool available for that DBMS. This is a whole new discussion (outside the scope of this Q/A), but it can be done "formally" (with a working company database) or "less-formally" using a docker-based database for your project use. Again, docker-based databases can be an interesting and lengthy discussion.
   2. Insert into a file-based database (sqlite, duckdb). Both of those options allege supporting file sizes well over what you would require for this data, and they both give you the option of querying subsets of the data as needed from R. If you don't know the [`DBI`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/index.html) package or DBI way of doing things, I strongly suggest starting at https://dbi.r-dbi.org/ and https://db.rstudio.com/.
   3. Splitting the file and then read piece-wise into R. I don't know if you can fit the entire data into R, but if you can and the act of reading them in is the hurdle, then

      ```sh
      split --lines=1000000 onebigfile.csv smallerfiles.csv.
      HDR=$(head -n 1 onebigfile.csv
      sed -i -e "1i ${HDR}" smallerfiles.csv.*
      sed -i -e "1d" smallerfiles.csv.aa
      ```

      where `1000000` is the number of rows you want in each smaller file. You will find `n` files named `smallerfiles.csv.aa`, `*.ab`, `*.ac`, etc ... (depending on the size, perhaps you'll see three or more letters).\

      The `HDR=` and first `sed` prepends the header row into all smaller files; since the first smaller file already has it, the second `sed` removes the duplicate first row.
2. Read each file individually into R or into the database. To bring into R, this would be done with something like:

   ```r
   files <- list.files("mypath", pattern = "^out.csv$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
   library(data.table)
   alldata <- rbindlist(lapply(files, fread))
   ```

   assuming that R can hold all of the data at one time. If R cannot (either doing it this way or just reading `onebigfile.csv` above), then you really have no other options than a form of database<sup>[2]</sup>.

   To read them individually into the DBMS, you could likely do it in bash (well, any shell, just not R) and it would be faster than R. For that matter, though, you might as well combine into `onebigfile.csv` and do the command-line insert *once*. One advantage, however, of inserting individual files into the database is that, given a reasonably-simple bash script, you could read the data in from completed threads while other threads are still working; this provides mid-processing status cues and, if the run-time is quite long, might give you the ability to do some work before the processing is complete.

---

Notes:

1. *"Shared filesystem"*: I'm assuming that these are not operating on a local-only filesystem. While certainly not impossible, most enterprise high-performance systems I've dealt with are based on some form of shared filesystem, whether it be NFS or GPFS or similar.
2. *"Form of database"*: technically, there are on-disk file formats that support partial reads in R. While `vroom::` can allegedly do memory-mapped partial reads, I suspect you might run into problems later as it may eventually try to read more than memory will support. Perhaps `disk.frame` could work, I have no idea. Other formats such as parquet or similar might be usable, I'm not entirely sure (nor do I have experience with them to say more than this).